# What will this print out and why? How would you fix it? [C++]

Tags: c++, class, header

The following prints out

```
0 2
```

It should print out

```
1 2
```

I try to go through line by line and it ends where UtilsA.cpp returns 0 through its GetNumber() function. It is exactly the same as UtilsC.cpp and that returns the correct number. What can I do to resolve this and why is it happening?

## UtilsA.h

```
namespace UtilsA {
    int GetSingleNumber();
}
```

## UtilsA.cpp

```
#include "UtilsA.h"

namespace {
    class A {
    public:
        int GetNumber() const { return Number; }
    private:
        int Number = 1;
    };
    A SingleNumberA;
}

int UtilsA::GetSingleNumber() {
    return SingleNumberA.GetNumber();
}
```

## UtilsB.h

```
namespace UtilsB {
    int GetSingleNumberA();
    int GetSingleNumberC();
}
```

## UtilsB.cpp

```
#include "UtilsB.h"
#include "UtilsA.h"
#include "UtilsC.h"

namespace {
    class B {
    public:
        B() : NumberA( UtilsA::GetSingleNumber() ), NumberC( UtilsC::GetSingleNumber() )  {}
        int GetNumberA() const { return NumberA; }
        int GetNumberC() const { return NumberC; }
    private:
        int NumberA;
        int NumberC;
    };
    B SingleNumberB;
}

int UtilsB::GetSingleNumberA() {
    return SingleNumberB.GetNumberA();
}

int UtilsB::GetSingleNumberC() {
    return SingleNumberB.GetNumberC();
}
```

## UtilsC.h

```
namespace UtilsC {
    int GetSingleNumber();
}
```

## UtilsC.cpp

```
#include "UtilsC.h"

namespace {
    class C {
    public:
        int GetNumber() const { return Number; }
    private:
        int Number = 2;
    };
    C SingleNumberC;
}

int UtilsC::GetSingleNumber() {
    return SingleNumberC.GetNumber();
}
```

## Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "UtilsB.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << UtilsB::GetSingleNumberA() << " " 
    << UtilsB::GetSingleNumberC() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I believe the reason is the order of initialization between translation units is not guaranteed. In the constructor for B. There is no guaranty that `SingleNumberA` or `SingleNumberC` were already constructed.

Comment: Read here about this: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use

Answer (score 1):

I was curious because I did not understand the cause of the problem, but all credits should go to [drescherjm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487892/drescherjm), I just confirm his answer here.

The problem was reproducible from the code and following the instructions in [isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use) it can be solved. Replace UtilsC.h with:

```
namespace {
    class C {
    public:
        int GetNumber() const { return Number; }
    private:
        int Number = 2;
    };
    C& SingleNumberC() {
        static C* ans = new C();
        return *ans;
    }
}

int UtilsC::GetSingleNumber() {
    return SingleNumberC().GetNumber();
}
```

and do the same for UtilsB.h than it should work.